# How to use javascript to find the middle point lat long of an image?

Tags: javascript, image

I have an jpg image of 500 x 400 pixels. I know that at the pixel: 20x20, it is of latitude longitude **X**. I also know that at a second pixel: 400x100 its of latitude loingitude **Y**. Given that, how can I find out what is the latitude+longitude of the center pixel of the image? I want to know this because I have a photo of a map of an area of those dimensions that I want to display on top of a google map.

Example:
Say I have a 500x400 pixel photo of a map of a top down picture of a amusement park.
I know Attraction 1 of the amusement park is located at (latitude,longitude) **X**
I know Attraction 2 of the amusement park is located at (latitude,longitude) **Y**
Since I know that... I want to know what the middle latitude longitude is in the center of the image. That way I can "approximately" draw it at the right spot on a google map.

Comment: Can't be done with the information you have. You either need to know (1) the long/lat of a second pixel, or (2) the pixel spacing - how many degrees of latitude per pixel or how many pixels per degree of latitude.

Comment: Goog for ***Find pixels from google map lat long***. Have you?

Comment: I've updated question to include the assumption the 2nd pixel is also known. That goog did not help.

Comment: I do not understand "I know that at pixel: 20x20, **it is of latitude longitude** **X**". Can you please explain?

Comment: Maybe if you add a picture example of what you have and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rolando: So you want to know the coordinates on the 500x400 image that are in the center of the rectangle made with X and Y, right? http://imgur.com/gallery/WcwiXrq

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the image you're working with and you want the coordinates on the 500x400 image of the center of the box box made by X and Y?

[image: map]

Your variables:

- `C` = the center -- **this is what you're looking to find**

  - [image: C_{x}] = the X coordinate of C
  - [image: C_{y}] = the Y coordinate of C
- `X` = the top left of the inner box

  - [image: X_{x}] = the X coordinate of X -- `20` in your case
  - [image: X_{y}] = the Y coordinate of X -- `20` in your case
- `Y` = the bottom right of the inner box

  - [image: Y_{x}] = the X coordinate of Y -- `400` in your case
  - [image: Y_{y}] = the Y coordinate of Y -- `100` in your case

The solution:

- [image: C_{x}]
- [image: C_{y}]

Basically, for [image: C_{x}] and [image: C_{y}] you find the respective centers in the inner box and add the offset the inner box has to the parent box. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, but X has pixel coordinate and latlong pair, Y is the same. I am looking for C's latlong pair (assuming I can get the center pixel coord).

Answer (score 0):

This is not something linear.  Unfortunately, you do not have enough information.  You need to know the projection and datum of both and make some conversions.

See also:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection